# Upload files to Google Drive using Rest API Rotates(Flips) the Image

Tags: google-drive-api

I am trying to upload files from salesforce to google drive using the upload endpoint.

Below is my code:

```
   Blob file=newAtt.Body;
   String fileName=newAtt.Name;
   String fileType=''; 
   String boundary = '----------9889464542212';
   String delimiter = '\r\n--' + boundary +'\r\n';
   String close_delim = '\r\n--' + boundary + '--';
   String bodyEncoded = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(file);
   String body=delimiter+'Content-Type: application/json\r\n\r\n'+'{ "title" : "'+ filename+'",'+' "mimeType" : "'+ filetype+ '", "parents" : [{"id" : "'+folderId+'"}]}'+delimiter+'Content-Type: ' + filetype + '\r\n'+'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n'+'\r\n'+bodyEncoded+close_delim;
   System.debug('body' + body);
   Http http = new Http();
   HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
   req.setEndpoint('https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files?uploadType=multipart');
   req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' +accessToken);
   req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'multipart/mixed; boundary="'+boundary+'"');
   req.setHeader('Content-length', String.valueOf(body.length()));
   req.setBody(body);
   req.setMethod('POST');
   req.setTimeout(60*1000);
   HttpResponse resp = http.send(req);
```

> Now, the blob object that i am getting from salesforce, is viewed
>   correctly in correct orientation. But the same file when uploaded to
>   google drive it flips/rotates to 90 degrees.

**This doesn't happen for all the images**

I would like to know if there is any mistake in the code from my side or there is any other way to handle this.

**Some more details:**

I upload the image from mobile device to `salesforce` first and then from `salesforce` to `google drive`. The orientation in `salesforce` is correct.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with Google Drive API nor the codes. When I [upload images](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-uploads) from my computer to google drive, I get the same default orientation. You might have been rotating an image with a software and when you uploaded that image, of course it's going to follow the default orientation.

Save the image to your computer. The orientation you see there is the default orientation, the same which will be reflected when you upload that file.

Comment: The image when saved to computer has the correct orientation, but when uploaded to google drive changes orientation